# Regular expression, all entries of #valueN# in string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a next string - `"#Value# #value2# (#value3#) .. #valueN#"`
I need to write an regexp to get an array `["Value", "#value2#", "#value3#", "valueN"]`

I've tryied next:

```
  var regexp = /#([A-z]+)#/gi;
  var string = "#Value# #value2# (#value3#) .. #valueN#";
  string.match(regexp);
```

But I get only first and last entry of expression in the string, but I need to get all entries.

Notice that the entire string can change over the time, I need to get all entries of text between `#` symbols.

Thx for any advance.

Comment: `matches = string.split(' ');`?

Comment: Look into exec() instead of match()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The regular expression is missing digit part (`[0-9]` or `\d`):

```
> "#Value# #value2# (#value3#) .. #valueN#".match(/#[a-z\d]+#/ig)
["#Value#", "#value2#", "#value3#", "#valueN#"]
```

---

BTW, `/[A-z]/` matches not only alphabet, but also characters between `Z` and `a`: `[`, `\`, `]`, `^`, `_`, `` ` ``. Be careful!

```
/[A-z]/.test('[')
true
```

Maybe you mean `/[A-Za-z]/` or `/[A-Z]/i` or `/[a-z]/i` ?

Comment: Oh god. Thank you very much. Forget about digit in the end :))))

Comment: I wanted to get any symbol between two `#` except - `#`, so `A-z` is not a mistake

Comment: @Maris, Oh, I see. Then, you can use `/#[^#]+#/` or `/#.+?#/`.

Comment: one more question. But how to remove `#` from the results?

Comment: @Maris, Try `"#Value# #value2# (#value3#) .. #valueN#".match(/#.+?#/g).map(function(x) { return x.substring(1,x.length-1); });`

Comment: @Maris, or `"#Value# #value2# (#value3#) .. #valueN#".match(/#.+?#/g).map(function(x) { return x.replace(/#/g, '') });`